# Is this a valid ISO 8601 formatted string?

Tags: datetime, iso8601

Is the following date string a currently valid ISO 8601 formatted string?

```
2016-09-18T17:34:02.666Z
```

On the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for 8601 I don't see this format, however it is specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: Yes, it is valid. It's basically extended in terms of subsecond support, but that's allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

according to the documentation here: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
The proper formatting is:

```
 YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD
```

so yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a valid ISO 8601 date.

Check for more details about the JSFiddle and related answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20012/online-tool-for-checking-iso8601)